custom form field ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'writeValue') at setUpControl
I developed a custom componet as form field, for doing so I implemented  a directive following this article on mediumenter link description here,
this is the directive:
import { Directive, forwardRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appValueAccessor]',
  standalone:true,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ValueAccessorDirective),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class ValueAccessorDirective<T> 
implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy
{
  private onChange: any;
  private onTouched: any;
  private valueSubject = new Subject<T>();
  private disabledSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  readonly value = this.valueSubject.asObservable();
  readonly disabled = this.disabledSubject.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.valueSubject.complete();
    this.disabledSubject.complete();
  }

  valueChange(v: T) {
    if(this.onChange)
    this.onChange(v);
  }

  touchedChange(v: boolean) {
    if(this.onTouched)
    this.onTouched(v);
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.valueSubject.next(obj);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabledSubject.next(isDisabled);
  }

}

this is the component that import the directive, that should be my custom form field:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit,Input, EventEmitter,Output, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import {  FormsModule,  ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule, SearchbarCustomEvent } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ValueAccessorDirective } from '../../directives/valueAccessor/value-accessor.directive';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  standalone:true,
  imports:[
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ], 
  inputs:['data','multiple','itemTextField','value'],
  selector: 'app-searchable-select',
  templateUrl: './searchable-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchable-select.component.scss'], 
  hostDirectives:[ValueAccessorDirective],
  changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SearchableSelectComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges,OnDestroy {
isOpen = false
@Input() value = {}
@Input() title = "Search"
@Input() data:any[]
@Input() multiple= false
@Output() selectedChanged:EventEmitter<any> =  new EventEmitter()
@Input() itemTextField= 'name'
disabled = false
text =""
touched = false
selected =[]
filtered =[]
subscription = new Subscription()

  constructor(
    private valueAccessor:ValueAccessorDirective<{value:string,key:string,selected:boolean}[]>
  ){
   this.subscription.add( valueAccessor.value.subscribe((v)=>{
      console.log("subscription", v)
    }))
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
  writeValue(obj: string): void {
    this.value = obj
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
isDisabled=isDisabled
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
this.filtered = this.data
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   
    if(this.value){
      this.selected.push(this.value)
    }
    if( !this.multiple){
      this.data.forEach(d=>{d.selected = false})
      this.selectedChanged.emit([this.value])
    }
  }




  open(){
    this.isOpen=true
  }
cancel(){
  this.isOpen= false
}
       select(){
        this.isOpen= false
       }

itemSelected(item){
  console.log("clicked",item )
  //remove not selected item
  this.selected = this.multiple? this.data.filter((item)=>item.selected):[item]
  this.valueAccessor.valueChange(this.selected)
  this.valueAccessor.touchedChange(true)
  this.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.selected)
 if(!this.multiple){ //  we can select only one item
  this.data= this.data.map(d=>{
     if(d['key']!= item['key'])
      d['selected']= false
    return d
  })
 }
  this.selectedChanged.emit(this.selected)
  this.isOpen= false
 
}

filter(event:SearchbarCustomEvent){
const filter = event.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()
this.filtered = this.data.filter(item=>{
  return  this.leaf(item).toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter)>=0
})
}


leaf= (obj)=>obj[this.itemTextField]
}

after  I added the field to the form I get this error message in the console of chrome:
core.mjs:8400 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'writeValue')
    at setUpControl (forms.mjs:2939:23)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.mjs:4771:9)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.mjs:5321:43)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:5266:18)
    at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1521:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2444:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2403:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2354:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9059:17)
    at ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:9042:5)

the component works as expected, but it is no part of the form. this is the first time I  have used standalone component and  this directive, I do not think that the poblem is related to the directive.
